# CloudFront what to use for Origin Domain Name when connecting to Wordpress

Tags: reverse-proxy, wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Wordpress site set up at `site.example.com` and I am trying to configure a CloudFront distribution as a reverse-proxy to reduce the load to my origin server.

In the past I have used Cloud**Flare** and the configuration was very straightforward, because CloudFlare knew the IP address of the origin server it could just send requests to that IP address along with SNI and the requests would get to the correct place.

e.g.

`site.example.com@[CloudFlare IP Address] -> CloudFlare -> site.example.com@[Origin IP Address]`

However it seems Cloud**Front** works slightly differently, it expects the origin server to be a Domain Name and not an IP address, so I suspect that as soon as I modify my DNS to point `site.example.com` to my CloudFront distribution's domain name then CloudFront will no longer be able to access the origin, as it will be pointing to itself

Now to overcome this in an ordinary webserver I would just create a second DNS record, e.g. `cf-site.example.com` and on the webserver configure that to serve the same content as `site.example.com` CloudFront could then access the Origin at `cf-site.example.com` and my customers would access the site as normal.

However with Wordpress if you try to do this as soon as you access the site on cf-site.example.com it will see that this name does not match the Site Address and immediately return a 301 which redirects you to the Site Address, in this case `site.example.com`. This causes an infinite loop and breaks the site.

I have found plenty of guides online on how to use CloudFront with Wordpress, so it must be possible, and I suspect I am just missing something obvious

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be overcome by forwarding the Host headers to the Origin, there is an Behaviour setting for this: **Cache Based on Selected Request Headers**